# How to use Unity's injectionfactory for child containers in ninject?

Tags: inversion-of-control, ninject, unity-container

I am stuck with ninjects equivalent to this unity registration:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<MyFactory>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());

// resolve instances once per child container by MyFactory
container.RegisterType<IMyInstance>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), 
                                    new InjectionFactory(c => c.Resolve<MyFactory>().GetMyInstance()));
```

Already tried to this without any effect:

```
var kernel = new StandardKernel();
kernel.Bind<MyFactory>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();

// context preserving get should do the job for child containers, right?
// thought in call scope ist the equivalent to unity's hierarchical lifetime manager?
kernel.Bind<IMyInstance>().ToMethod(ctx => ctx.ContextPreservingGet<MyFactory>().GetMyInstance())
                          .InCallScope();
```